# What is the plural form of the phase "play a role"

Tags: phrase-usage, plural-forms

We often say something/someone plays a ... role in something. But what if the subject is in a plural form? For example dogs. Can I say "dogs play a big role in the security" or should I say "dogs play big roles in the security" In some article, people even say "[dogs play big role](http://pittsburgh.cbslocal.com/2014/05/12/dogs-play-big-role-for-elephant-handlers-at-pittsburgh-zoo/)" Which one is correct or more naturally used?

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct, but have different meanings.

"Dogs play big roles..." <-- This says that there are multiple different and important roles that are fulfilled by dogs in general.

"Dogs play a big role..." <-- This means that dogs in general play a common important role.

Comment: Maulik V's answer also pointed out a fair point -- it may be headlinese, that special application of a language that the press uses to save space, and in some cases sow some mild confusion to sell papers / get clicks.

Answer (score 1):

When you use 'plural', you ***still*** count them as one entity, don't you? That said, if one dog plays a big role in securing something, many dogs *collectively* play **the same role**.

Thus, it's *fine* to say...

> Dogs play a big role in...

As far as your link is concerned, it's [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese) where authors take all freedom to *eat up* the articles! :)